# Calendar reading hangs my android application

Tags: java, android, calendar

**Why this code:**

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm");
String dateNow = formatter.format(c.getTime());
```

hangs my android application?

Can it be uses fault? Why is this happening?

Comment: This code is probably not hanging your app: http://ideone.com/FMwjf7. If you remove it, does it still hang?

Comment: Not sure why it hangs up your app but you probably should change `"yyyy/mm/dd HH:mm"` to `"yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm"` since `mm` are minutes and `MM` are months.